# What to enter on the check ordering form?

Tags: check, checking-account, personal-check

I want to order checks for my Bank of America checking account from a third party, but I don't know how to complete the checkout form:

[image: Checkout form]

Suppose my numbers were:

Account number: 1234 5678 9012
Routing number (paper&electronic): 123 456 789
Routing number (wires): 234 567 890

What should I enter on the first four textboxes of the checkout form?

My **wild guesses** are
123456789012123456789
123456789
123456789012
001

EDIT: When I first opened the account, I received a few free checks (three, I think) and I have used them all (I think). This was a long time ago and I never made copies of them.

EDIT2: Also, if I buy 'singles' checks from the retailer, does that mean those checks are for other people to deposit to my account or for me to deposit to other people's accounts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might cost more money, but you can use the banks own system to order checks. That way you know they have the right routing and account numbers. When you buy a box of checks they will generally have an order form in the box, that will guide you through the process. But you don't have one because this is your first order, or you lost the paper a long time ago. Still use the banks website to order the checks, it is worth the extra few bucks.

The check number is not a big deal. Some people want to avoid low numbers because it looks like they have a new account. In fact I have seen some merchants reject low number checks. They might call them starter checks. They are afraid of fraud. (I have no comment on the logic or appropriateness of their concern, I am only noting that I have seen the signs).

Just guess high. Don't worry if the first few checks started with 001 or 101, so start with 1001. You don't even have to use the bundles of checks in the right order, the bank software won't reject them. Some couples each have a bundle of checks, and write them against the same account. The bank might get concerned if the same number appeared close together, but if they were years apart they won't even notice.

Some banks use singles and some use duplicates:

**Duplicates** have a carbon sheet under each check. When you buy something at the store you fill out the info (store name, amount in number, amount in words, date, signature). You then tear out the top copy. The carbon left behind has all the important info (what you wrote and check number). When you go home you can then update whatever manual or electronic system to use for tracking your money.You can also use the register part of the checkbook to record this info. For safety the carbons don't include all the bank info, that way if you lose the carbon, somebody can't get all the banking info.

**Singles**: There is no carbon copy. Some have a stub on the top or the side that you can jot down the vital info. You can also use the register part of the checkbook to record this info.

Both types of checks are used to spend your money. You give them to stores or people, or send them in the mail. They then deposit them in their bank account.

Comment: Unfortunately, the bank charges 4x as much as the retailer, so I still want to figure out how to put the numbers in the form.

Comment: You pay the higher price for one box. You also have the problem that the printer needs to know the address on the bank. I have no idea what that should be, but it could be on the website, it would be one one of the starter checks.

Comment: Even one box is too much for my needs. I just need 12 of them for my lease. I don't want to support that rip-off from the official source. I'll contact my bank to figure out what to put on the address field and I'll cross-check my father's checks against his account info to figure out what to put on the ordering form.

Comment: Does you bank have bill pay? They can send a check from the bank either electronically or via mail.

Comment: The landlord doesn't want to give his account/routing number for me to do it electronically.

Comment: They can mail it to a home/business address.

Comment: Thanks. If I still take the chance and order the checks, would you agree that the above wild guesses are good guesses (the only modification being the increased starting check number)?

Answer (score 2):

You should find one of these checks that you used and copy the data from there. I don't have an account with BOA, thankfully, but I believe you can have access to scanned checks through your online account just as with any other US bank.

If not - stop by a branch tomorrow and ask them to help you with filling these. Mistake in a routing number can cost dearly when you write a check from someone else's account.

You should make sure the account number and the routing number are correct, and that the starting check number is **higher** than the last check you've used on this account.

Comment: When I first opened the account, I received a few free checks (three, I think) and I have used them all (I think). This was a long time ago and I never made copies of them. I can access my account number and routing numbers online.

Comment: But it can't be 001 if you already had a check with that number, can it? So go back to your statements and find these checks.

Comment: I know for sure that I have only used a few. Is it safe to go with 020?

Comment: I should also add that I want to order them to pay towards other accounts not for others to write to mine. If I buy 'singles' from a retailer, does that get me what I want?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what "singles" are. Checks are usually from paying from your account to others. What I meant was that if you make a mistake in these numbers, you may inadvertently draw money not from your account as you intended, but from someone else's.